# Copy data from remote MySQL server

Tags: mysql, copy

I have two MySQL servers on different location. I would like to copy some data from one table on one server to another server. And that process is automated and executed scheduled. Is it possible to do it with php?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a cron job. The job can execute a php script. Just google it

Answer (score 0):

Yes with provisos...

1. you will need access to both servers on the MySQL port (through the
   firewall)
2. you'll need the users set up in the database (in the relevant
   `mysql` tables) to give read/write permissions
3. you'll need a Cron job to perform the scheduling